# Apply filters to different paths of the same URI in Spring Cloud Gateway

Tags: spring-cloud-gateway

I have filters defined like this:

```
- id: Some route
      uri: http://localhost
      filters:
        - name: Filter1
        - name: Filter2
      predicates:
        - Path=/api/**
```

However, I would like to apply Filter2 only to /api/somepath/** and keep Filter 1 as it currently is. I've tried to put Filter2 in it's own route, but then it's not picked up anymore:

```
    - id: Some route1
      uri: http://localhost
      filters:
        - name: Filter1
      predicates:
        - Path=/api/**

    - id: Some route2
      uri: http://localhost
      filters:
        - name: Filter2
      predicates:
        - Path=/api/somepath/**
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch the order of route definitions. Define *Some route2* first and then *Some route1* like this

```
- id: Some route2
  uri: http://localhost
  filters:
   - name: Filter2
  predicates:
   - Path=/api/somepath/**

- id: Some route1
  uri: http://localhost
  filters:
   - name: Filter1
  predicates:
   - Path=/api/**
```

In your configuration, path is always matching with *Some route1* and that's why first configuration is picked

Comment: Thanks, I figured this out as well, but you're right, this is the answer!